# Eclipse CSS plugin support css imports

Tags: css, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there any CSS plugin for Eclipse, which supports import CSS files to profile, e.g. like Spket IDE
makes it for JavaScript files.
In result, I want to get the following functionality:

In any html/css file, where defined css class/id, I perform clicking on it, 
and it dispatches me to appropriate css file which responsables for that style,
or shows me in left side panel it styles.

Does anyone know such plugin for CSS Eclipse?

Thanks,

Comment: Aptana has such functionality I think

Answer (score 0):

Check out Aptana Studio as a Plugin to Eclipse PDT (for php developers). Do not try the stand alone version as it lacks some of the functionality. It is a great plugin for a web developer.